# How to exclude all rows with the same ID based on one record's value in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

Say I have the results above, and want to exclude all rows with ID of 14010497 because at least one of the rows has a date of 2/25. How would I filter it down? Using a `WHERE table.end_date > '2019-02-25'` would still include the row with a date of 2-23

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
  select * from your_table
  where id not in (
     select distinct id
     from your_table
     where end_date > '2019-02-25'
     )
  /
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.end_date = '2019-02-25'
                 );
```

I strongly advise using `not exists` over `not in` because it handles `NULL` values much more intuitively.  `NOT IN` will return *no rows at all* if any value in the subquery is `NULL`.

Comment: good point re: NULL, however, "IF" ID is a PK, or such, it wouldn't be allowed to be NULL ... ;)  OP would need to clarify if that's an issue in this case or not, though.

Comment: @Ditto . . . I avoid `NOT IN` specifically so this does not have to be resolved on a case-by-case basis (that introduces room for error).